# Why isn't my Enumerable getting populated by Glass.Mapper?

Tags: c#, sitecore, glass-mapper

I'm totally confused as to why this isn't working. I have a class with a list of other classes as a property of it:

```
public class Widget
{
     ....
     public virtual IEnumerable<WidgetButton> Buttons { get; set; }
}

[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{B615973D-59F6-437E-9827-BA3A40068C69}", AutoMap =true)]
public class WidgetButton : BasePage
{
     [SitecoreField]
     public virtual string Title { get; set; }
}
```

My sitecore item has a TreeListEx with one item in it:

[image]

and I'm reading this item thus:

```
Widget widgetTest = SitecoreContext.GetItem<Widget>(new Guid("{4FF5B96F-9606-4581-95F7-B6A7BAA4C28F}"));
```

My `Widget`(`widgetTest`) contains all of the data out of sitecore, **but the buttons**!? The Buttons property is just an empty list. What am I missing I've tried several configurations, Publishing, etc. According to the [Glass.Mapper tutorials](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial4) this should work

---

### Glass configuration

**Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor.config**

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <initialize>
                <processor type="RR.Web.Website.App_Start.GlassMapperSc, RR.Web.Website" />
            </initialize>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc.Config**

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
      <settings></settings>
    <pipelines>



      <mvc.getModel>
        <processor type="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel, Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc"/>
      </mvc.getModel>

    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

---

Going directly to sitecore I can get my item:

```
Sitecore.Data.Database context = Sitecore.Context.Database;
var item  = context.GetItem(new ID("{4FF5B96F-9606-4581-95F7-B6A7BAA4C28F}"));
```

`item` contains a field called `Buttons`, the `value` of this field is the GUID of the item in the treelist (`{3C18BF9F-9906-4807-83B9-73CA08E61C39}`).

If I query this directly I can see the button:

```
var buttonItem = context.GetItem(new ID("{3C18BF9F-9906-4807-83B9-73CA08E61C39}"));
```

so everything appears perfectly fine! Why isn't glass mapper mapping this?

Comment: Can you add your Glass configuration for `Widget` as well? Using attribute config on it as well I assume?

Comment: Can you try adding `[SitecoreField("Buttons")]` on your IEnumerable property or adding `[SitecoreType(AutoMap =  true)]` to the `Widget` class

Comment: @jammykam I tried adding those attributes, didn't help.

Comment: @techphoria414 XML added above. I've tried several variations of attributes onto the object but nothing seems to make a difference. I'm going to do some reading on the configuration now. I didn't set this up and I've not used glass mapper before so it's very likely this that is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution, don't ask me why this works because I found it though trial and error. Basically doing this seemed to make it work:

```
[SitecoreType(AutoMap =true)]
public class Widget
{
     ....
     [SitecoreField(FieldType =SitecoreFieldType.TreelistEx)]
     public virtual IEnumerable<WidgetButton> Buttons { get; set; }
}
```

specifically I think specifying the `FieldType`.

Comment: Well done. Is there another field called buttons floating around? Normally you wouldn't need to specify the field type.

Comment: Actually there was, I noticed it after writing this question. But I removed it, cleared out the recycle bin and even renamed the field! The only thing that seemed to make a difference was the above.